# Checking a JSON POST API with Pingdom

Tags: pingdom

Is there any way to add a check in Pingdom that makes an HTTP POST request to an API with a JSON POST body? I see in their advanced configuration screen that you can specify a POST body but it indicates that it sends the request as a form post, not JSON.

I tried specifying the JSON in the POST body section and setting the "Content-Type" header manually to "application/json", but that doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

We just set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` and it worked nicely.